# How to create a custom link of partner profile?

Tags: wordpress

I create a link of my partner profile which is https://oneforother.com/members/webeasyc_dating/profile/edit/group/7/

When I login some other id my link is not working because webeasyc_dating is my user name that time but now I am login another id so it's not working. I want a link which contain on pick a current user id and appear partner profile of this id.

[screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMW6o.jpg)

Comment: This might be better suited as a question in the Webmasters Exchange: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this a WordPress problem specifically? If so, maybe the WordPress website - with much more detail please. Also, there's no need to append "please anyone help me" to questions - especially titles! - readers know you want help, and begging won't help.

Comment: thanks yes it's wordpress problem